# How do you remove permissions in Crafter Studio 2.5?

Tags: java, content-management-system, crafter-cms

In the permission-mappings-config.xml file we have the following rules for a group:

```
  <allowed-permissions>
    <permission>Read</permission>
    <permission>Create Content</permission>
  </allowed-permissions>
```

But the users still have the "Copy" and "Request Publish" options when they right click a page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CrafterCMS, the action Request Publish is automatically granted to all users who don't have `Publish` permission. There is no way to turn that off at this time.

With regard to `Copy`, the permission copy means you read the item to the clipboard, and having a read permission is enough to allow the user to copy. Paste however requires a `Write` permission to the destination.

As you probably guessed, `Cut` requires `Read` and `Delete` from source, and `Write` to destination.

Hope that helps.